# Have to double click li to open my link

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with a search box that has a dropdown. In the dropdown there are links but to open the links I have to double click them. Here is a link to my jsfiddle of it https://jsfiddle.net/ag7L02u0/. Anyone have a solution?
HTML:

```
        <form class="search" method="post" action="" >                  
            <input type="text" name="inputSearch" id="inputSearch" placeholder="Search Username" autocomplete="off" />
            <ul class="search-ac" id="user-result">
                <li><a href="#">Search Result #2<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Search Result #3<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Search Result #4</a></li>
             </ul>
             <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" Style="display:none;">
         </form>
```

CSS:

```
.search {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    margin-top:5px;
}
.search input {
    height: 26px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 12px 0px 25px;
    background: white url("../img/search.png") 8px 6px no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #a8acbc #babdcc #c0c3d2;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px #fcfcfc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px #fcfcfc;
}
.search input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border-color: #66b1ee;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
}
.search input:focus + .search-ac {
    display: block;
}

.search-ac {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #fdfdfd;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}
.search-ac:hover {
    display: block;
}
.search-ac li {
    display: block;
    z-index: 100000;
}
.search-ac li:first-child {
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.search-ac li:first-child:before, .search-ac li:first-child:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border: 5px outset transparent;
}
.search-ac li:first-child:before {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
    top: -11px;
}
.search-ac li:first-child:after {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
    top: -10px;
}
.search-ac li:first-child:hover:before, .search-ac li:first-child:hover:after {
    display: none;
}
.search-ac li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.search-ac a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 -1px;
    padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
    color: #808394;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px white;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index:110;
}
.search-ac a span {
    font-weight: 200;
}
.search-ac a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: url("../img/arrow.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.search-ac a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background: #338cdf;
    border-color: #2380dd #2179d5 #1a60aa;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #a7aabc;
    font-weight: 200;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #a7aabc;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 14px;
}

::-webkit-search-decoration,
::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.lt-ie9 .search input {
    line-height: 26px;
}
.btn-default{
    float:right;
    margin-top: -38px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your href attribute to something else than "#"?

Answer (score 0):

I tried tour example and put there

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_">
```

works fine

Comment: I think it's something to do with the fact I'm loading the li's dynamically using ajax depending on what people are typing because it takes 2 clicks with that

Comment: if I understand you, in this way load also the the herf value

Answer (score 0):

Works for me? I just added www.google.com in the href and target="_blank" (so i didn't navigate away) and it re-directs. What are you doing with the links in your real document please.